# LeafletSlider not working with layerGroup

Tags: javascript, slider, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to use [dwilhelm89:s LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) to visualize the recent Ebola outbreak in west Africa.
When using a single layer the slider is working fine, but when I try to add layers into a layerGroup I get a console message reading: "You have to have a time property".
I have the time property, the layers is working if I add them separately, just not in the layerGroup.

Live example with my [faulty layerGroup](http://wwwe.aftonbladet.se/redaktion/martin/ebola/circle_group.html)

**What am I doing wrong?**
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks! Martin

Comment: Well the notification says clearly that you don't have the "time" property. And you don't, you only have "pointToLayer". This is what I can see from a quick look. If you want a better answer, separate the js from the html so it can be edited live.

Comment: In my CartoDB-table I have a column with dates, named time. When I run the single layer I get no complain about "time" property, only when I try to add multiple layers to a layerGroup. But, I'm on deep waters here, I don't fully know what I'm doing. [Here is my code in a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martinhedstrom/h9hgy0pg/1/), I added the data as geojson, so there is no ajax-call to CartoDB in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you [use your browser debug tools](http://debugbrowser.com/), you'll also see that the request to CartoDB is failing because your query is malformed.

Comment: Would you mind explain what's wrong with the query to CartoDB?